Google Calendar webcal link fails in Google Calendar android app with "Calendar no longer exists"
Testing calendar links with the Android Studio emulator for Pixel 8 Tiramisu. Expecting the link to load the Google Calendar application and prompt to add an event, but it has an error.
The Google Calendar link points to a feed using the webcal protocol, for example https://www.google.com/calendar/render?cid=webcal%3A%2F%2Fdemo.site.com%2Fical, the Google Calendar application opens but the event feed fails to load properly with the "Calendar no longer exists." error on screen.


It's because demo.site.com doesn't exist. You should test with a qualified URL which should point to a ICS file.

No. That's not the reason. Also happens with existing ics files and I am pretty sure the author did not use demo.site.com at his actual setup.
